# line-delimited json format txt file, how to import with pandas

Tags: json, pandas, txt

I have a line-delimited Json format txt file. The format of the file is .txt. Now I want to import it with pandas. Usually I can import with

```
  df = pd.read_csv('df.txt')
  df = pd.read_json('df.txt') 
  df = pd.read_fwf('df.txt')
```

they all give me an error.

1. ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 29 fields in line 1354, saw 34
2. ValueError: Trailing data
3. this returns the data, but the data is organized in a weird way where column name is in the left, next to the data

can anyone tells me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_json('df.txt', lines=True)
```

[read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) accepts a boolean argument `lines` which will `Read the file as a json object per line.`